# Heroku logs H18 (503) error but I'm sending error 400 to the client from my node.js app?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I'm sending an error message to the client with status 400 but the logs show Heroku error H18 `Server Request Interrupted`. I'm logging also the request-id before sending 400 to make sure I'm watching the same request.

```
heroku[router] info sock=backend at=error code=H18 desc="Server Request Interrupted" method=POST path="/api/v1/email" host=getinvoicesimple.com request_id=b332c22a-78dd-423f-926e-11ae3497d67d fwd="86.150.146.32" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=103ms status=503 bytes=267 protocol=https
```

The app is pretty simple and as it's being aborted before doing anything more complex, I don't see any reason for that. 
The entrypoint is a multipart post

```
router.post('/api/v1/email', function(req, res) {

  const appVersion = req.header('x-is-version');

  if (!appVersion) {
    console.error(`App version is required. ${req.headers['x-request-id']}`)
    return res.status(400).send('App must be updated.').end()
  }
  ...
  /// The rest of the function
})
```

Comment: Try removing `.end()`. `send()` should call it for you automatically.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem only for multipart/form-data